# Why can't I use AngularJS to load a JSON file and angular route in the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm not a native speaker, sorry for my unclear question.
I'm trying to use AngularJS to read a JSON file. I did it but when I use angular route in the same page, the angular route didn't run. Then I figured out that I can only use one function in 1 page. For more clearly, here is my code:

In home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="UpStore">
<head>


 </head>
 <body ng-controller="ProductController">

 <div ng-view> </div>

 <!--Javascript-->

 <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-
route.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>

    var app = angular.module("UpStore", [])
    app.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "productdata.json"
        }).then(function mySucces(respone) {
            $scope.products = respone.data
        }, function myError(respone) {
            $scope.dataError = respone.statusText
        }
            )
    })

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var App = angular.module('UpStore', []);

App.controller('ProductController', function ($scope) {


});

var App = angular.module('UpStore', ['ngRoute']);


App.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider



    .when('/men', {
        templateUrl: 'men.html',


    })


    .when('/product', {
        templateUrl: 'product.html',




    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'men'
    });
});

App.controller('ProductController', function ($scope) {


});
```

In men.html:

```
 <div ng-repeat="pd in products">
    <p>{{pd.ID}}</p>
    <p><a href="#product"><img src="image/{{pd.Image}}" /></a></p>
 </div>
```

I also has one more question. In page men.html, I have several products, each product has an ID. I have a page product.html to show the product details. What I want to do is when I click on an image of a product in page men.html. The URL to the product.html would be like product.html/productid. I know that $routeParams can solve my problem, but I don't know how to write the code.

I really need some help because I've been struggling with these 2 problems for hours. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are continuously overwriting the previously defined modules.

As you have already defined the module `UpStore` in the *app.js*

```
//Define it only once
var App = angular.module('UpStore', ['ngRoute']);
```

You need to get the reference of it in the script block and use.

```
//Get the reference to existing module
var app = angular.module("UpStore"); 

//Use it
app.controller(.......)
```

Additionally: Note always use same version of *angular.js* and *angular-route.js* library